# Resolve with ParameterOverride breaking change from 5.9.0 onward

Tags: unity-container

I'm upgrading my existing application from Unity 4.0.1 to 5.11.1. In doing so  calls to Resolve using ParameterOverride are failing to call the appropriate parameterized constructor. The default constructor is always called.

I put together a simple console application to demonstrate the issue. When built with the Unity nuget package 5.8.13 the parameterized constructor is called. Updating the nuget package to 5.9.0 causes the default constructor to be called. This is then the same for all subsequent versions.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Default ctor");
    }

    public MyClass(string myParameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parameterized ctor");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        unityContainer.Resolve<MyClass>(new ParameterOverride("myParameter", "ABCD"));
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the ParameterOverride to match the parameterized constructor. Has something changed in 5.9+ parameter overrides?